# Display Bitmap resource in MainScreen banner for BlackBerry

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Hey guys,
I'm having trouble displaying my icon in the banner of my MainScreen. The Icon is located in the res/ directory. Here's my MainScreen code:

```
    HorizontalFieldManager mngr = new HorizontalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH);

    LabelField label = new LabelField("AACD");
    BitmapField pic=new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("res/aacdIconSmall.PNG"),Field.FOCUSABLE);

    mngr.add(pic);
    mngr.add(label);

    this.setBanner(mngr);
    BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField();
    add(browserField);
```

The AACD Label shows up above my BrowserField but my pic bitmap never shows up. Any ideas?

Comment: Try Bitmap.getBitmapResource("aacdIconSmall.PNG")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is OK.

However I do suspect you did not add the image to your JDE project, so the image is not included in the resulting `.cod` file during building the project.

Comment: My res folder is definitely being included in the build. When I run my debug, it doesn't throw any errors with that image directory.

Comment: I concur with Arhimed, whether fully qualified ("res/...") or not, if it is in the .cod, that method will create it.  The fact that it throws a runtime error with the unqualified name is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use res folder

try Bitmap.getBitmapResource("img/aacdIconSmall.png")

the folder should be like this

res
 - img
    - aacdIconSmall.png

(i dunno is accdIconSmall.PNG is case-sensitive or not, have not tested yet, just make sure you are using the same upper and lower case)